# How to install specific version of Chromium on Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, apt, google-chrome, chromium

I've Ubuntu 18.04 and it has Chromium 80 installed on it. I want to downgrade it to `Chromium 79.0.3975.79` hence trying to install it.

With command `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`, it installs latest version. To install specific version, I tried -

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser=79.0.3975.79
```

but it gives - Version 79.0.3975.79 for chromium-browser not found.

Could you please help me how to downgrade chromium?

**Note:** I am trying to install `chromium` not `chrome`

Comment: There's no such version for 18.04 as you're trying to install, check here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/chromium-browser

Comment: it's 79.0.3945.79 not 79.0.3975.79

Comment: Yes by mistake I placed `3975`, my intention was `3945`

Answer (score 1):

The version you're trying to install for 18.04 is wrong. Correct version is `79.0.3945.79` there's also newer 79 version available.

You can add Chromium Team official repository:

```
git clone https://git.launchpad.net/~chromium-team/chromium-browser/+git/snap-from-source
```

Here's the list of available packages in 18.04 [click here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/chromium-browser)

Answer (score 0):

In a typical install of Ubuntu, Apt will automatically try to install the highest version it can locate in any repository that it knows about.

Manually browsing to the international, US and IL repositories did confirm your requested version is not available for download.

If you would like a specific version, please choose from the available ones at the repository: [international repository chromium pool](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/) (you don't have to actually use this specific repo).

While using a browser, you can also manually download the debian, or use wget from the terminal, but I would simply suggest using apt-get.